# Laravel Sqlcommand could not retrive result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

In phpmyadmin MySQL command is ok and that can be fetch result correctly. After using this command with QueryBuilder result set is empty.

MySQL Command :

```
SELECT created_at
FROM `entryExit`
WHERE `userId` =1000
AND `insertDate` = DATE( CURDATE( ) )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Result:**

```
created_at
2014-06-30 05:53:18
```

laravel QB:

```
$checkSave = DB::table('entryExit')
            ->select(DB::raw('created_at'))
            ->where('userId', '=', Auth::user()->userId)
            ->where('insertDate', '=', 'DATE( CURDATE() )')
            ->get();
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: what's the raw output of: `Auth::user()->userId`?

Answer (score 2):

try changing:

```
...
->where('insertDate', '=', 'DATE( CURDATE() )')
...
```

to

```
...
->where('insertDate', '=', DB::raw('DATE(CURDATE())'))
...
```